# No Data found Query failed in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have to fetch data from 3 tables that is (players, tournaments,entries, and groups) and show that data on the web page but I am not getting any of the data on the table when I use join it shows nothing while I used just a single select * from entries to get the fees data but not getting the other data when i write query using join :

i want to show the below data to the output :

[Output that i want to show on page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7vGW.png)

```
<?php
include_once('assets/config.php');
include_once('functions.php'); 


 

// Check the connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// Retrieve data from the database
$sql = "SELECT tournaments.tour_name, entries.fees, players.f_name, groups.group_name
FROM entries
JOIN tournaments ON entries.tour_id = tournaments.tour_id
JOIN players ON entries.player_id = players.player_id
JOIN groups ON entries.group_id = groups.group_id;
";





$result = mysqli_query( $conn, $sql )or die( mysqli_error( $conn ) );




// Create the HTML table with border and styling
echo "<table style='border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;'>";
echo "<thead style='background-color: #ddd;'><tr><th style='padding: 8px; border: 1px solid #ddd;'>Player</th><th style='padding: 8px; border: 1px solid #ddd;'>Tournaments</th><th style='padding: 8px; border: 1px solid #ddd;'>Group</th><th style='padding: 8px; border: 1px solid #ddd;'>Fees</th></tr></thead>";
echo "<tbody>";

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {  
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {


      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td style='padding: 8px; border: 1px solid #ddd;'>" . $row["f_name"] . "</td>";
      echo "<td style='padding: 8px; border: 1px solid #ddd;'>" . $row["tour_name"] . "</td>";
      echo "<td style='padding: 8px; border: 1px solid #ddd;'>" . $row["group_name"] . "</td>";
      echo "<td style='padding: 8px; border: 1px solid #ddd;'>" . $row["fees"]. "</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
  }
} else {
  echo "<tr><td colspan='4' style='padding: 8px; border: 1px solid #ddd;'>No data found.</td></tr>";
  printf("Query failed: %s\n", $conn->error);
}

echo "</tbody></table>";




// Close the database connection
$conn->close();

?>
```

[Current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtlXD.png)

How can i query it perfectly show the ouput

Comment: could you share mysql database structure ?

Comment: https://ibb.co/4SQHbXx

check this link i have shared the image

Comment: so, you have zero items in your database. first try to add some item to your db.
and I need your structure of each table, to give you better information.